# Regex matching string inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all occurrences in a string, for example

```
{{Syed Waqar Ameen|User|60feab5768e2da001960caf7}} your phone
number will help {{Syed Waqar Ameen|User|60feab5768e2da001960caf7}} 
your phone number will help {{Syed Waqar Ameen|User|123}} your 
phone number will help {{Syed Waqar 
Ameen|User|60feab5768e2da001960caf7}} your phone number will help 
dsdf {{dsdfsfcvxcvxcv|sdfsdf|60feab5768e2da001960caf7}}
```

It should match `{{Syed Waqar Ameen|User|60feab5768e2da001960caf7}}` but it should not match `{{Syed Waqar Ameen|User|123}}`

Currently regex I am using is

`/{{.*?[0-9a-fA-F]{24}}}/gm`

Its only partially working, Any help would highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `.*?` I think this part is the culprit.

Comment: `{{[^}]*[0-9a-fA-F]{24}}}`, replace `.` with the negated character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure that dupe answers the question. Since the first match matches everything

Comment: show some clear examples

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks it worked